# Stop Multiple Windows Service Simultaneously

Tags: powershell

I have multiple windows service and there are no dependencies between them. I want to stop all the windows services at the same time. I don't want to stop all the services one by one. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The `-name` parameter of the `Stop-Service` command is an [array strings][1]. You can pass multiple services to it.

```
Stop-Service -name service1,service2,service3
```

**Edit**

```
[string[]]$services = @('service1', 'service2')
Stop-Service -Name $services -NoWait
while ((Get-Service -Name $services | Where-Object { $_.status -ne 'Stopped'}).Count -ne 0)
{
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
```

Comment: I have tried this command, but it's not stopping services at the same time. I am getting below output.

`WARNING: Waiting for service 'MyFirstService1 (MyFirstService1)' to stop...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'MyFirstService1 (MyFirstService1)' to stop...`

Comment: @ankitthakkar - I misunderstood your requirement. In that case, you can not use Stop-Service like this. You'd have to wrap each stop service in a job or async procedure but even then, you can never be sure they all stop **at the exact same time**. Each will get **a stop command** at around the same time though.

Comment: I am using the stop-service command to stop all the service by using -NoWait but I also want that it will not move to the next step till all services will stop.

Comment: In that case, you can write a loop to check if all services are stopped. I have added this to my answer

Comment: I have resolved this using loop and `WaitForStatus` Argument of service.

Comment: Thanks @Lieven for your support !!!

Comment: @ankitthakkar - You are welcome. I didn't know `WaitForStatus` myself.